# Printing to the console vs writing to a file (speed)

Tags: c++

In C++, which would be faster if repeated, say, 5000 times:

```
cout << "text!" << endl;
```

or

```
my_text_file << "text!" << endl;
```

(writing to a file vs. cout-ing to the console)

Edit:

I ask because when writing to the console, you see all the text being printed which seems like it would slow down the loop. In a file, you arn't seeing the text being printed, which seems as if it would take less time.

Just tested it:

Console: > 2000 ms using endl and \n

File: 40 ms with endl and 4 ms with \n

Comment: You can't make sure what is the standart output being redirected for, but disk access (like writing on a file) is _much_ slower than ram access (printing console).

Comment: @Julio: Have you tested this in a real environment ever? Printing to console is usually much slower than writing to disk, it is not just leaving the characters in a buffer, but the buffer is limited, and the contents of that buffer need to be moved to the video card (a real text terminal) or drawn on the screen (a graphical terminal) with enough data, the intermediate buffer fills, and the writer process stalls waiting for the output to be drawn... Before making this type of *strong* statements on performance, actually measure, in a real environment with enough data you will see that yourself.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas +1: really interesting, thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Writing to a file would be much faster. This is especially true since you are flushing the buffer after every line with `endl`.

On a side note, you could speed the printing significantly by doing repeating `cout << "text!\n";` 5000 times, then flushing the buffer using `flush()`.

Comment: This will probably sound dumb... What exactly is the buffer?

Comment: When you output something to a stream (such as cout), whatever you send is stored in a buffer before it is actually put there (flushed). It happens every now and then, and when the program's execution completes correctly. However, using flush or endl explicitly flushes it. This just ensures that things get printed when we want them to.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that much faster...

A test of `1 million couts` with endl (clear buffer):

Results:

```
console cout time: 2.87001
file cout time: 2.33776
```

Code:

```
class Timer
{
        struct timespec startTime, endTime;
        double sec;
public:
        void start();
        void stop();
        double getSec();
};

void Timer::start()
{
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &startTime);
}
void Timer::stop()
{
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &endTime);
        sec = (endTime.tv_sec - startTime.tv_sec);
        sec += (endTime.tv_nsec - startTime.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
}
double Timer::getSec()
{
        return sec;
}


int main(){
        int ntests = 1000000;
        Timer t1 = Timer(), t2 = Timer();

        t1.start();
        for(int c=0;c<ntests;c++)
        {
                cout << "0" << endl;
        }
        t1.stop();

        ofstream out("out.txt");
        streambuf *coutbuf = cout.rdbuf();
        cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf());
        t2.start();
        for(int c=0;c<ntests;c++)
        {
                cout << "0" << endl;
        }
        t2.stop();
        cout.rdbuf(coutbuf);

        cout << "console cout time: " << t1.getSec() << endl;
        cout << "file cout time: " << t2.getSec() << endl;
}
```

Build and run:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -lrt && ./test && rm out.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to console I/O generally being relatively slow, the default configuration of the standard streams `cout` and `cin` has some issues that will greatly slow performance if not corrected.

The reason is that the standard mandates that, by default, `cout` and `cin` from the C++ iostream library should work alongside `stdout` and `stdin` from the C stdio library in the expected way.

This basically means that `cout` and `cin` can't do any buffering at all in its internal `streambuf`s and basically forwards all I/O operations over to the C library.

If you want to do anything resembling high performance I/O with the standard streams, you need to turn off this synchronization with

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

before doing any I/O.

Answer (score 1):

Writing the same amount of data, with the same buffer size to the console will most definitely be faster than writing to a file.

You can speed up your write speed (both for console output, and file output) by not writing out the buffer with every line (i.e.- don't use std::endl after every line, as it both adds an endline to the stream, and writes the buffer).  Instead use "\n" unless you need to ensure the buffer is output for some reason.

Comment: Unless you're outputting over a very slow serial link.

Comment: Including all that printing and scrolling that would be visible while printing to the console? In a text file, you wouldn't be seeing the text being written.

Comment: Writing to the console is faster, but if the write operation is all that's performed, then a program writing to a file will probably finish first.

Comment: @vorbis5: you don't necessarily see it in a terminal either. When I worked for a financial data provider, the server logs were written too fast to tail in the Solaris xterm of the day but no problem in rxvt precisely because it was smart enough to limit redraws per second and let data pass through invisibly, but the last N lines were still there in the buffer if you bothered to scroll back.  Still, a fixed-length in-memory buffer's less stress to maintain than growing a file on magnetic disk.