# Writing to standard out vs writing to file

Tags: java, linux, io

This is similar to:

[Printing to the console vs writing to a file (speed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338812/printing-to-the-console-vs-writing-to-a-file-speed)

I was confused because there are two conflicting answers. I wrote a simple java program

```
 for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++){
       System.out.println(i);
 }
```

and ran it with `/usr/bin/time -v java test` to measure time to output to stdout, then I tried `/usr/bin/time -v java test > file` and `/usr/bin/time -v java > /dev/null`. Writing to console was slowest (10 seconds) then file (6 seconds) and `/dev/null` was fastest (2 seconds). Why?

Comment: [Because `/dev/null` is web scale.](http://www.mongodb-is-web-scale.com/)

Comment: try minimizing the console window

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because writing to console needs to refresh the screen each time something is written, which takes time.

Writing to a file needs to write bytes on disk, which takes time, but less time than refreshing the screen.

And writing to `/dev/null` doesn't write anything anywhere, which takes much less time.

Comment: +1 When you write lots of data to these output devices, it has to actually do something with the text and you program has to wait for it to do it. i.e. when the program is producing text too fast it is forced to slow down for the consumer.  The device to read from/write to is often more important than what you do in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem with System.out.println is that System.out by default is in autoflush mode, println practically switches off buffering. Try this

```
    PrintWriter a = new PrintWriter(System.out, false);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        a.println(i);
    }
    a.flush();
```

and you will see that output to a file becomes ten times faster.

Comment: Ah, I see. Would be convenient if there was a flag to switch on/off buffering on System.out.

Comment: That's one of the reasons why logging APIs are used.